# React Native: TypeError: null is not an object

Tags: java, react-native

This is the activity starter code:

**ActivityStarterModule.java**:

```
    final class ActivityStarterModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    ActivityStarterModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ActivityStarter";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    void navigateToExample() {
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainViewActivity.class);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    void dialNumber(@NonNull String number) {
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    void getActivityName(@NonNull Callback callback) {
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            callback.invoke(activity.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } else {
            callback.invoke("No current activity");
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    void getActivityNameAsPromise(@NonNull Promise promise) {
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            promise.resolve(activity.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } else {
            promise.reject("NO_ACTIVITY", "No current activity");
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    void callJavaScript() {
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            MainApplication application = (MainApplication) activity.getApplication();
            ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost = application.getReactNativeHost();
            ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = reactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager();
            ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();

            if (reactContext != null) {
                CatalystInstance catalystInstance = reactContext.getCatalystInstance();
                WritableNativeArray params = new WritableNativeArray();
                params.pushString("Hello, JavaScript!");


            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to link the java file to the javascript file and I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: null is not an object(evaluating 'reactNative.NativeModules.ActivityStarter.Mainapplication').
```

PS: I'm just trying to get my bearing with ReactNative